# If $\triangledown$ is a connection, show that $\frac{1}{2}\triangledown$ does not satisify the product rule and is thus not a connection.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, connections

If $\triangledown$ is a connection, show that $\frac{1}{2}\triangledown$ does not satisify the product rule and is thus not a connection.

---

My attempt:

I'm a bit confused here on how to evaluate $\frac{1}{2} \triangledown_X fY$. Is the point of this to show that $\frac{1}{2} (\triangledown_X fY) \neq (\frac{1}{2} \triangledown)_X fY$?

$(\frac{1}{2} \triangledown)_X fY = XfY +f\frac{1}{2} \triangledown_X Y$

$\frac{1}{2} (\triangledown_X fY) = \frac{1}{2}(XfY +f \triangledown_X Y)$

And thus the product rule is not well defined with the connection $\frac{1}{2} \triangledown$.

I'd appreciate some insight on this one, thanks!

Comment: The product rule is well-defined for $\frac12\triangledown$, but it's false. It's the second equation of the three in the question. You're given that the same equation without the two factors $\frac12$ holds, because $\triangledown$ is a connection. Dividing that by $2$, you'd get the second equation except that you'd also have a factor $\frac12$ on the $XfY$ term. So your second equation won't hold unless $XfY=0$. (It will hold in $0$-dimensional manifolds, but that's not interesting.)

Comment: So the point is, it's not a well defined connection because the second equation does'nt equal the third equation unless $XfY=0$?

Comment: Right. The third equation is what's true (given that $\triangledown$ is a connection), and the second equation is what's needed (to make $\frac12\triangledown$ a connection).